# Copy range to the bottom of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro that loops through a "source" sheet and for each value in column A, copy a range from template sheet to a destination sheet. After the template range is copied, I need to change a few values in destination sheet based on the source sheet value. Right now I am trying to get the copy working. The copy is failing with error 1004 'The information cannot be pasted because the Copy area and the paste area are not the same size.'

```
Sub CopyRangeFromOneSheetToAnother()
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim shtSource As Worksheet
    Dim shtTemplate As Worksheet
    Dim shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim sResourceName
    Dim rngCalcTemplate As Range


    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set shtSource = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set shtTemplate = wb.Sheets("res_tpl")
    Set shtDest = wb.Sheets.Add

    '--set range for copying. Hard-coded for now would be nice if it would auto shrink/expand
    Set rngCalcTemplate = shtTemplate.Range("A2:M7")

    'Find the last row (in column A) with data.
    iLastRow = shtSource.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    '--loop through source sheet and copy template range to dest for each

    For iSourceSheetRow = 2 To iLastRow
        sResourceName = shtSource.Cells(iSourceSheetRow, 1)
        rngCalcTemplate.Copy shtDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add the sheet before `Rows.Count` too, `shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.Rows.Count).End(xlDown)`. Otherwise, the `rows.count` will run on whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.  Not sure if that'll fix it, but it should help. (If that doesn't fix it, you just need to adjust the paste *to* range to be the same size as the copied one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the following line of your code:

```
rngCalcTemplate.Copy shtDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown)
```

If you place your cursor at the very last cell in column A (i.e. at `"A" & Rows.Count`, possibly `A1048576`) and then press <kbd>Ctrl-Down</kbd>, you are still at the very last cell in column A.

If you then try to paste 6 rows of information starting at that cell, there won't be room to do so - there is only one row of "pastable" area to use.

You are probably wanting to find the row following the last used cell in that column, so your code should be:

```
rngCalcTemplate.Copy shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```